# Using pROC package in R to obtain CI for SP and SN from specific threshold

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

Using the `pROC` package, is anyone aware of a way to get confidence intervals for SP and SN with an input of a specific threshold value, rather than a specific SP or SN value? `ci()` appears to only display SP and SN values using their corresponding SN or SP's as an argument; I can ask for the CI of SP at an SN of 0.8, but not for the CI of SP at a threshold value of 9.0.

I understand that I can just find the SP/SN values for a threshold and then use these as arguments for `ci()`, but that seems clumsy. Of course, this may just end up being a question for the package developers.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Sounds great; I'll tag it for migration. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confidence intervals for SN and SP can be calculated for specified thresholds as an option when the roc object is first created as well as from `ci.thresholds(rocobj, thresholds=0.9)`

With sample data from the help files for `pROC`:

```
library(pROC)
data(aSAH)

rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, ci=TRUE, of="thresholds", thresholds=0.9)
```

giving

> ```
> 95% CI (2000 stratified bootstrap replicates):
>  thresholds sp.low sp.median sp.high se.low se.median se.high
>         0.9      1         1       1      0   0.04878   0.122
> ```